# Thymeleaf: An error happened during template parsing

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm getting this error "An error happened during template parsing" when I click a button in index.html to change the view to new.html

This is the error description

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/new.html]")
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:241) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:366) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1400) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1145) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1084) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

This is the New page

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Create New Client</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/4.5.2/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src= "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
    <h1>Create New Client</h1>
    <br />
     <div class="col-sm-4">
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/save}" th:object="${client}" method="post">

      
        <div alight="left">
            <tr>
                <label class="form-label" >Client Name</label>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}" />
                    <input type="text" th:field="*{clientname}" class="form-control" placeholder="Client Name" />
                </td>
            </tr>
         </div>   
            
            <div alight="left">
          
            <tr>
                 <label class="form-label" >Hookah</label>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{hookah}" class="form-control" placeholder="Hookah" /></td>
            </tr>
            </div> 
            <div alight="left">
                 <tr>
                 <label class="form-label" >Fee</label>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{fee}" class="form-control" placeholder="Fee" /></td>
            </tr>
            </div> 
            <br>
            <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Save</button> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is My Controller

```
package com.demoproject.PostavteTroikyBar.controller;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.demoproject.PostavteTroikyBar.Service.ClientService;
import com.demoproject.PostavteTroikyBar.domain.Client;

@Controller
public class ClientController {
    
     @Autowired
        private ClientService service;

        @GetMapping("/")
        public String viewHomePage(Model model) {
            List<Client> listclient = service.listAll();
            model.addAttribute("listclient", listclient);
            System.out.print("Get / "); 
            return "index";
        }

        @GetMapping("/new")
        public String add(Model model) {
            model.addAttribute("client", new Client());
            return "new";
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String saveStudent(@ModelAttribute("client") Client std) {
            service.save(std);
            return "redirect:/";
        }

        @RequestMapping("/edit/{id}")
        public ModelAndView showEditStudentPage(@PathVariable(name = "id") int id) {
            ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("new");
            Client std = service.get(id);
            mav.addObject("student", std);
            return mav;
            
        }
        @RequestMapping("/delete/{id}")
        public String deletestudent(@PathVariable(name = "id") int id) {
            service.delete(id);
            return "redirect:/";
        }
}
```

The error occurs when I press to move to New.html from the main page, please see code below:

```
<div align = "center" >        
         <h3><a  th:href="@{'/new'}">Add new</a></h3>     
    </div>
```

Would be thankful for any help or suggestions regarding how to fix this issue

Comment: You can [edit] your question to provide the full Java stack trace for the Thymeleaf error (as formatted text). There will be a specific message in there, with more details. The error may be related to something you have not shown us in your question, or may provide more specific guidance.

Comment: I was wrong - in your case, there is no specific message, for some reason. The exception type `TemplateInputException` usually means the template file could not be located. I don't think it is relevant, but you can try changing the file name from `New.html` to `new.html`, to match what you have in your code (`return "new";`). Also, you don't need 2 namespace declarations in the template - you can just use `<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">` - but, again, I doubt that is the cause of your problem in this case.